# R print all ggplot graphs in markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I have dataframe like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


dt <-
  expand.grid(
    month = seq(1, 12),
    agent_id = seq(1, 1000)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(sales = row_number())
```

I would like to print graphs for all agent_id in markdown so I created this plot

```
src <- dt %>% filter(agent_id == 2)
title <- as.character(src$agent_id)

ggplot(src, aes(x = month, y = sales, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = title)
```

But how can I do it without calling

> src <- dt %>% filter(agent_id == 2)

and

> src <- dt %>% filter(agent_id == 3)

until  1000 or even higher id?

Answer (score 1):

You could `split` you dataset by `agent_id`, put your plotting code in a function then use `iwalk` to loop over the splitted list where `iwalk` allows to pass the name of the list element as a second argument to the plotting fcuntion to be used as title and the combo of `iwalk` + `print` avoids any console output:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
date: "2022-08-16"
---

```{r include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dt <-
  expand.grid(
    month = seq(1, 12),
    agent_id = seq(1, 3)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(sales = row_number()) 
dt_split <- split(dt, dt$agent_id)
```

```{r}
purrr::iwalk(dt_split, function(x, y) {
  p <- ggplot(x, aes(x = month, y = sales, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = y)
  print(p)
})
```
````

[image]